# Is it possible to rename a tag to its synonym?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The [etag](/questions/tagged/etag) tag is incorrectly named: it should be [etags](/questions/tagged/etags) because that is how the program it is named after called. While [etags](/questions/tagged/etags) is a synonym, this situation is suboptimal. As far as I can tell, SO is the only place which associates [etag](/questions/tagged/etag) with emacs etags program, the main meaning of [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) is an Entity Tag in HTTP.

Proposal: rename tag [etag](/questions/tagged/etag) to [etags](/questions/tagged/etags) and *not* make [etag](/questions/tagged/etag) its synonym.

Comment: I can remove the synonym and fix the [tag:etag] tag wiki, but there's nothing I can do about all of the incorrect taggings.  Those will have to be fixed one at a time.

Comment: A mod can, and did, remove the synonym. The disambiguation has to be a community effort.